# can i save my unmanaged packages in my local pc?

Tags: unmanaged-package

I want to know if i can save my unmanaged packages in my local pc, or if it only save in salesforce.

If I want to save my unmanaged packages for use after  in other Org, can i do it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Development tools such as the [Force.com IDE](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE) (and others - see this [Force.com Tools and Toolkits](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Tools) list) allow configuration and code from one org to be extracted to your local PC and then pushed from there into a different org.

If you don't need the IDE facilities, the [Force.com Migration Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool) - Ant tasks - can be used instead as they are only concerned with transferring the configuration and code from/to orgs.

(And once you have got the configuration and code onto your local PC you can then add it to a version control system so you can better track changes.)

But see Sebastian's important point about the unmanaged code being installable without needing to do the transfer to your PC.

Answer (score 1):

Veronica, Salesforce code and packages live in the cloud. This doesn't mean you can't download a copy of your code. In fact, most of us do this daily by using tools like Eclipse or Mavens Mate.

However, regardless of whether you have a copy of your code or not, the actual act of packaging happens online. Once you created your package, Salesforce will email you a link (and it'll be available online too). With that link, you can install your unmanaged code in any org you wish to.